# php stripe payments API

Tags: payment

Hello I am writing a simple test script to look at using Stripe payments. I have the following config file:

```
<?php
//require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
//require('stripe-php-master/lib/stripe.php');
$stripeClassesDir = __DIR__ . '/stripe-php-master/lib/';
$stripeUtilDir    = $stripeClassesDir . 'Util/';
$stripeErrorDir   = $stripeClassesDir . 'Error/';
set_include_path($stripeClassesDir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $stripeUtilDir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $stripeErrorDir);
function __autoload($class)
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $class);
    require end($parts) . '.php';
}


$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "123",
  "publishable_key" => "456"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

I have changed the keys temporarily.
However when I use it the "pay with card" button seems to work, but I get the error : require(Request.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
I am not using composer.

Answer (score -1):

All libraries installed when installing Stripe?
https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php

Here are the methods of preparing to work with the API
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard#prepare-your-api